# Streaming video from Door Station of Hikvision (DS-KV8102-IP)

Tags: curl, camera, video-streaming, hikvision

I need to start Two way audio with Door Station camera Hikvision (DS-KV8102-IP)
I am using Curl to test:

`curl --digest -u admin:admin http://192.168.1.224:8102/ISAPI/System/status`

It return:

```
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

I set http port for this camera is 8102 but it did not make scene. I also tested with ivs4200 which provided by Hikvision: Camera ran fine. I have change port from 1-9999 but there are no any port work in this case.

I have test with other camera: DS-2CD2143G0-I, DS-2DE2A404IW-DE3. It ran fine.

Do you have any command to make this camera work? Do I need to change port or anything on this camera?

Comment: Is there any API to communicate with DoorBell station? Please share with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DS-KV8102-IP (and all this series) has no webGUI and cannot enable CGI. It only supports SDK from Hikvision website. I got those information from Hikvision technical support team.

Comment: Don't trust chinese "technical support team" :) The SDK I've working with (for other HikVision cameras) is just (badly working) wrapper for plain HTTP REST API. Mentioned camera may not have WEB UI, but most probably have REST API. @AD Max - run a sniffer, see what protocol is used for interaction with iVS4200 or SDK